# chromedriver is not opening the profile I want it to

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

Even when I use this code, it opens chrome as a guest user.

Comment: Did you think about using a UserAgent? May it resolve you problem ? cf https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/

Comment: How is that relevant to this? What problem does it solve?

Answer (score 0):

As you are in [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system, you need to pass the name of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant along with the extension, i.e. *`chromedriver.exe`*.

So you need to change the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\foo\bar\chromedriver', options=options)
```

With:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\foo\bar\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work